# Construction of a bounded map which is the identity or the null operator on the space of square integrable functions using the Helmholtz decomposition

Tags: real-analysis, ordinary-differential-equations, operator-theory, sobolev-spaces, boundary-value-problem

Let $\Omega$ be a bounded open subset of $\mathbb{R}^3$ and $n$ the outward-pointing unit normal to the boundary of $\Omega$. We know that the space $(L^2(\Omega))^3$ of square integrable functions admits the following orthonormal decomposition:
$$
(L^2(\Omega))^3=\nabla H_0^1(\Omega) \oplus H(div\,0,\Omega), 
$$ 
where

$div$ is the divergence operator, $\nabla$ the gradient operator,

$H^1_0(\Omega)$ is the usual Sobolev space,

and $H(div\,0,\Omega):=\{u\in (L^2(\Omega))^3|div(u)=0\}$.

We want to construct a bounded operator defined on $(L^2(\Omega))^3$ such that its restriction on the subspace $\nabla H_0^1(\Omega)$ is the identity operator and the other one on the subspace $H(div\,0,\Omega)$ is the null operator. Thanks.

Comment: Search for [Helmholtz decomposition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_decomposition) / Helmholtz projection; the results will include various [lecture notes](https://www.wias-berlin.de/people/john/LEHRE/NUM_NSE_14/num_nse_2_7.pdf) on the subjects.

Comment: @bro: Thank you for the hint. But, I still stuck in finding an explicit representation of the Helmholtz projection.